# How to lower the width of a XAML ToggleSwitch (Width attribute not working for me)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I do not manage to properly set the width of my XAML ToggleSwitch.

My code is as follows:

```
<Controls:ToggleSwitch OnLabel="True" 
                       OffLabel="False" 
                       IsEnabled="{Binding CheckValueEnable}" 
                       IsChecked="{Binding CheckValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="250" >
</Controls:ToggleSwitch>
```

Whatever Width value I set, there is a too big spacing between the text (true / false) and the visual toggle button.
How can I decrease this spacing?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by there is to much space? Can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your issue (over exaggerated a little) is something like this:

{O          }___________True

What you want is:

{O          }__True

Without knowing the control it is  a bit difficult but i would guess you only option is to modify the ToggleSwitch's ControlTemplate to define the content presenter position

**EDIT:**
Further to that, you might find the following article useful as it describes the process of editing controls in XAML

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-editing-control-templates

Comment: You perfectly understood the issue, I could not have stated it in a more understandble way :)